# How to check if there was any change in a Formik form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a page with a form and, if the "return" button is pressed, I need to show a dialog asking the user if he wants to save the form only if the form has changed.

Is there a way to easily check if the form has changed without having to compare every individual field to the `initialValues` object?

Answer (score 4):

formik has a variable in the formik "props" called "dirty". its automatically calculated. https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#dirty-boolean

Comment: Very simple to import and use!

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I've found so far is to use [lodash.isEqual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.isequal). Then, you can compare the props `initialValues` and `values` to check if anything has been changed.

Comment: this compares values to the initial state. But what if you want to know if values have changed between submits?

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the touched fields by accessing `formik.touched`

[image]
[Docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik)

Comment: `touched` doesn't mean that u changed something, it means that input was focuesd

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean flag (state) and change it to `true` inside `onChange` event on every field.

Comment: There should be a better way to do so